# Android app run error - Activity class .MainActivity does not exist

Tags: java, android, react-native

I've been building a React-Native app and all seems good when running the iOS simulator, however I am struggling to get the Android simulator to start the whole thing getting the old familiar:

```
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.companyname.companynameapp/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.companyname.companynameapp/com.companyname.companynameapp.MainActivity} 
does not exist.
```

I have been through all of the internet's instructions and debugging to try and get this fixed, but nothing seems to help.

I believe that the app name was changed somewhat a long while ago, but this is the first proper time of trying to start it up in the Android simulator.

Some of the files I have seen people ask to check are:

- android/settings.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'companyname'
include ':app'
```

- android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

It may be here that something has gone amiss as I noticed the `<data...` entry is a different app name than what I've seen in other places... For context, say the company name is `Proctor and Gamble`, this shortened name will be like `PG`.

```
<application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    ...
    <activity
       android:name=".MainActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       ...
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
           ...
           <data android:scheme="shortedcompanyname-app" />
```

- android/app/build.gradle

```
...
android {
    ...

    namespace "com.companyname.companynameapp"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.companyname.companynameapp"
        ...
        manifestPlaceholders = ['appAuthRedirectScheme' : 'shortenedcompanyname-app']
```

- android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">companyname</string>
</resources>
```

- android/src/main/java/com/companyname/MainActivity.java

```
package com.companyname.companynameapp;
...
public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
    ...
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "companyname";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the manifest is definitely wrong:

```
<activity
   android:name=".MainApplication"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   ...
```

It should look like this:

```
<activity
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   ...
```

Comment: Ah, It is actually correct when I checked again. Apologies